# Using F() expression in Django update method

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I have a Django model called `Tree` representing tree objects and it contains `x` and `y` coordinate fields of type `FloatField`. I am trying to call Django's `update` method to initialize a `PointField` called `coordinates` for each tree object with the following command:

```
Tree.objects.all().update(coordinates=Point(F('x'), F('y')))
```

If I understood correctly from the documentation, I would need to use the `F()` expression to access the fields of each tree object at the database level.

However, this does not work and results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/src/app/app/tree_api/management/commands/update_coords.py", line 47, in handle
    Tree.objects.all().update(coordinates=Point(F('x'), F('y')))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/point.py", line 35, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Invalid parameters given for Point initialization.')
TypeError: Invalid parameters given for Point initialization.
```

What I'm trying to achieve could be done (with PostgreSQL and PostGIS) using the following raw SQL query:

```
UPDATE tree_column_name
SET coordinates = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || x || ' ' || y || ')');
```

Is it possible to initalize the `PointField` from `x` and `y` values using Django ORM's `update` method without having to write a raw SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with `Func`:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Func
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from yourapp.models import Tree

(
    Tree
    .objects
    .all()
    .update(
        coordinates=Func(F('x'), F('x'), function='ST_Point')
    )
)
```

Comment: I tried using `ExpressionWrapper` but I got the same error message `TypeError: Invalid parameters given for Point initialization`.

Comment: hu @mhyyppa, thanks about your comment. I updated the answer. Also, I didn't test with postgis. Let's try tou fix your issue :)

Comment: Using the `Func` operator and `ST_Point` gives the following error: `AttributeError: 'FloatField' object has no attribute 'srid'`.

Comment: Maybe using a raw SQL query isn't such a bad idea after all. The SQL query is quite simple so it is easy to keep it up to date with the database model. Also, this database operation needs to be executed only once when importing new data to the database.

Comment: Of course. You can do it with raw. But was cleanest using ORM. It's a pity we did not find the right expression.